# How do I build jaxen from source

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build, ant

I need to build jaxen version 1.1.6 using jdk 7 but I can't find the sources I can use to build it. I can't access http://jaxen.codehaus.org/ anymore as I think this is where I can find the sources. While I found this https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.6/ from the maven repository, I am not sure how I would be able to build the java sources. Whenever I build other jars, I use ant or maven but these are literal java sources (i.e. no build.xml). Is there an easier way of building these java sources? Or do you know where I can find the java sources with a readme at least on how I can build them?

Comment: May I ask why you want to rebuild them from source?

Comment: You can find the sources on Github [here](https://github.com/jaxen-xpath/jaxen), but I am also a bit perplexed as to why you would want to build it yourself (and especially building a version from 2013).